# Find the 1st and 2nd largest num in an array, O(log N) + O(N) version

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, tree, comparative-review

I have implemented the \$O(logN) + O(N)\$ version for the problem: How to find 1st and 2nd largest element in a *non-negative unique array*? The algorithm principle is from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628777/4928269).The comparison information in finding 1st helps find 2nd faster (\$log N\$ time).

But I am really depressed that my code is even slower than the easiest method. Theoretically, lower the numbers of comparison, smaller the cost time. I guess maybe my implementation need be optimized.

**Can anyone know how to make algorithm2 faster than the easiest method?**

---

Tested the code in VS2013, win 10, CPU i5 6500, release version.

The result: `algo1 30ms, algo2 96ms`.

My code, `mian.cpp`:

```
// You need focus on algo2 function.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "gettime.h"
using namespace std;

vector<int> algo1(vector<int> src_data);
vector<int> algo2(vector<int> src_data);
vector<int> generateRandNum(unsigned int size);

int main() {
    vector<int> src_data;
    vector <int> result;
    src_data = generateRandNum(10000000);

    uint64 t0 = GetTimeMs64();
    result = algo1(src_data);
    uint64 t1 = GetTimeMs64();
    cout << "Algo1 cost " << (t1 - t0) << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "1st: " << result.at(0) << " 2rd: " << result.at(1) << endl;

    t0 = GetTimeMs64();
    result = algo2(src_data);
    t1 = GetTimeMs64();
    cout << "Algo2 cost " << (t1 - t0) << "ms" << endl;
    cout << "1st: " << result.at(0) << " 2rd: " << result.at(1) << endl;

    return 0;
}

// generate unique random numbers in the range[0...N]
vector<int> generateRandNum(unsigned int size) {
    int num = 0;
    vector<int> src_data;

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
        src_data.push_back(i);
    }
    std::random_shuffle(src_data.begin(), src_data.end());

    return src_data;
}

vector<int> algo1(vector<int> src_data) {
    int max1st = -1, max2rd = -1;
    int record = 0;
    vector<int> result;
    // find maximum num
    for (size_t i = 0; i < src_data.size(); i++) {
        if (src_data[i] > max1st) {
            max1st = src_data[i];
            record = i;
        }
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < src_data.size(); i++) {
        if (src_data[i] < max1st && src_data[i] > max2rd) {
            max2rd = src_data[i];
        }
    }
    result.push_back(max1st);
    result.push_back(max2rd);
    return result;
}

vector<int> algo2(vector<int> src_data) {
    vector<vector <int>> matrix;
    // initial first row
    matrix.push_back(src_data);

    // build the tree using 2D vector
    int layer_size = src_data.size();
    int height = 0;
    int maximum = 0;
    int lastnode = 0;
    int newsize = 0;
    int num1, num2;
    int aplus = 0, isnegtive = 0;
    while (layer_size != 1) {
        newsize = layer_size / 2 + layer_size % 2;
        vector<int> new_row(newsize, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < layer_size / 2; i++) {
            num1 = matrix[height][2 * i];
            num2 = matrix[height][2 * i + 1];
            maximum = max(num1, num2);
            new_row[i] = maximum;
        }
        if (layer_size % 2) {
            lastnode = matrix[height].back();
            new_row[newsize - 1] = lastnode;
        }
        matrix.push_back(new_row);
        layer_size = newsize;
        height++;
    }

    int max1st = matrix.back().front();

    // find 2nd laygest number
    int index_record = 0;
    int max2rd = -1;
    int candidate = 0;
    int leftnode_index = 0, rightnode_index = 0;
    for (int i = matrix.size() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        leftnode_index = index_record * 2;
        rightnode_index = index_record * 2 + 1;
        if (matrix[i - 1][leftnode_index] == max1st) {
            candidate = matrix[i - 1][rightnode_index];
            index_record = leftnode_index;
        }
        else {
            candidate = matrix[i - 1][leftnode_index];
            index_record = rightnode_index;
        }
        if (candidate != max1st && candidate > max2rd) {
            max2rd = candidate;
        }
    }

    vector<int> result;
    result.push_back(max1st);
    result.push_back(max2rd);
    return result;
}
```

`gettime.h` is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1861337/4928269.

Comment: Did you compile -O3?

Comment: @pacmaninbw /O2 in VS2013.

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement this algorithm for yourself. But this is reasonably easy with the standard library `std::nth_element(src.begin(),src.begin()+1, src.end(), std::greater<int>());`

Comment: Also it is not surprising to me that that `algo1` is outperforming `algo2`. The algorithm suggested in the linked question may minimize the number of comparison operations - but you need to remember you're running on real hardware. `algo1` doesn't need to perform any allocations (other than the result vector) and is far more cache friendly. We can review this code here, but explaining the relative performance of the 2 algorithms is more likely a question for stackoverflow.

Comment: (Try _max_but1_ or _max2nd_ - I cringe sub-vocalising `max2rd`). O(logN) + O(N) is just O(N)… `algo1` can be improved by initialising `max1st` and `max2nd` to `src_data[0]` and just "handing down" max candidates to `max2nd` when `max1st` is exceeded: N-1 comparisons.

Comment: @cloakedlearning I want to test if the optimal algorithm valid, so I make my own implementation. Thanks for your method, it's really elegant. I also found that the time of memory allocation may harm the performance, so I want to know if there is smarter method can avoid it. Anyway, theory in class is really different with real-world scene.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @greybeard that's an answer ... You should write that as an answer

Comment: @Vogel612 Got it, so I should post a self-answer.

Answer (score 4):

Algo 1 still has a lot of headroom for improvement as well:

```
vector<int> algo1(const vector<int> &src_data) {
    int max1st = src_data[0], max2nd = src_data[1];
    if (max1st < max2nd) {
        swap(max1st, max2nd);
    }

    for_each(src_data.begin() + 2, src_data.end(), [&max1st, &max2nd] (const int &n) {
        if (n > max2nd) {
            if (n > max1st) {
                max2nd = max1st;
                max1st = n;
            } else {
                max2nd = n;
            }
        }
    });

    vector<int> result;
    result.push_back(max1st);
    result.push_back(max2nd);
    return result;
}
```

For starters, avoid copying `src_data` on invocation. That is easily 50% of the function cost with the original solution, and 70% for the OP's improved solution.

The second improvement, only ever perform the `n > max1st` comparison if `n > max2nd` has confirmed it as a potential candidate. Best case, the number of comparisons drops to \$n\$ with \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ assignments, and only the worst case remains \$2n\$ comparisons with \$2n\$ assignments.

A quick benchmark of the original, the [improved](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/141826/68973), and this implementation of `algo1` (when using the copy free function signature, best out of 3 each), took 19ms, 12ms and 8ms each.

Answer (score 2):

The recommendation in the linked article is correct, but you are taking it too literally. Take a look at the Stepanov's [solution](https://github.com/rjernst/stepanov-components-course/tree/master/code/lecture11). Pay particular attention to a `binary_counter` class, and how it is used. I highly recommend to watch the lecture ([part1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84gHZgPCf1s) and [part2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEDFrgRNwTc)) before digging into the code (I also highly recommend to watch a [complete course](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHxtyCq_WDLXryyw91lahwdtpZsmo4BGD)).

Answer (score 0):

Trying to take this literally: `Can anyone know how to make algorithm2 faster than the easiest method?` and `// You need focus on algo2 function.`, with algorithm2 *finding the runner-up among the champion's opponents in a tournament*.

The straightforward way to find the `k`-max values of an unordered collection is to feed a priority queue of size `k` with its elements.

The cases with `k` <= 2 are special in not warranting an explicit priority queue: after initializing `k` candidates from the first `k` elements, just compare each of the remaining elements to the current `k`-max candidate. If the current element is greater: if looking for the top two elements, compare to the max candidate: if greater, keep that value as the new runner-up and make the current element the max candidate, else just replace the runner-up.

This requires \$kN+O(1)\$ assignments, worst case, and \$kN-O(1)\$ comparisons.

The tournament approach to 2-max requires \$N+ld(N)-O(1)\$ comparisons and \$N+O(ld(N))\$ assignments.

According to this, algorithm2 *may* use slightly more than half the comparisons and assignments algorithm1 does. Then again, for "random input", I'd *expect* the number of assignments in the simplistic approach to grow in the ballpark of \$c*lg(N)\$ to \$c*sqrt(N)\$ - strictly lower than \$N/2\$ for "non-trivial" values of \$N\$.

For any *contemporary sequential machine implementation*, I'd expect simplistic to win hands down against tournament. Design, test, analysis and measurement of parallel renditions left as an exercise…

Comment: If bored, I might give the videos of A.Stepanov's lecture and/or your implementation of `algorithm2` another try or throw together implementations, even present them - don't hold your breath.

Comment: Ouch - started on the right hand with this one (very similar to [Ext3h's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/141832/93149)), deluded myself dry-running too few too small examples… with a version only working if the largest value followed the 2nd largest. Keeping the answer for reference, as a reminder, for lop-sided leers…

Answer (score 0):

This is a self-answer. Thanks for every reviewer.
I modified my code, and found the problem in the function `algo2()`. Allocation new memory for 2D vector is the chief culprit. I tested the execute time of `algo2` if there is only one operation `matrix.push_back(src_data)`:

```
// just for test, only one operation
vector<int> algo2(vector<int> src_data) {
    vector<vector <int>> matrix;
    matrix.push_back(src_data);

    vector<int> result;
    result.push_back(0);
    result.push_back(1);
    return result;
}
```

The excute time (compiled in release mode): `algo2` 41ms, `algo1` 28ms.
So my implementation is too much literally, the code should avoid the memory allocation as much as possible. Maybe I need new data structre or STL class with the full power of C++.

I also modified the `algo1`, faster slightly but more elegant than former version:

```
vector<int> algo1(vector<int> src_data) {
    int max1st = src_data[0], max2nd = src_data[1];
    if (max1st < max2nd) {
        swap(max1st, max2nd);
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < src_data.size(); i++) {
        // numbers of comparisons is still 2*N
        if (src_data[i] > max1st) {
            max2nd = max1st;
            max1st = src_data[i];
        }
        else if (src_data[i] > max2nd) {
            max2nd = src_data[i];
        }
    }
    vector<int> result;
    result.push_back(max1st);
    result.push_back(max2nd);
    return result;
}
```

Finally, without doubt finding 2nd largest element using a tree is faster than linear method due to the fewer number of comparison, but how to build the tree efficiently is a problem.

Comment: There is still room for improvement in algo1, you are doing twice as many comparisons as you would need. Only test for `(src_data[i] > max1st)` if `(src_data[i] > max2nd)` was true. Apart from that, why not using iterator, but index to access vector? (Latter one just being a matter of style, the difference should be minimal. If you want to push further though, you should use a local variable to copy `src_data[i]` by value.)

Comment: Oh, and the signature of `algo1` should be changed to `vector<int> algo1(const vector<int> &src_data)`. That copy of `src_data` is currently responsible for ~70% of the run time of that function.